# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (REACTJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export

I need import several functions to my component but I have this error:[image]

when the nintCards function is in the component everything works correctly but when I want to import it it gives me that error. In theory it can't read arrFoods so it says undefined but I passed the parameter to it so I don't know why it shows an error.

Thank you very much for your advice, it is of great help to me.

functionsParams.js

```
/* Refactoring functions */

const macrosIndex = (foodType, arrFoods) => {
  const indices = [];

  let idx = arrFoods.map((e) => e.type).indexOf(foodType);
  while (idx !== -1) {
    indices.push(idx);

    idx = arrFoods.map((e) => e.type).indexOf(foodType, idx + 1);
  }

  return indices;
};

const gMacrosIntCards = (macro, arrFoods) => {
  let gProtIntCards = [];

  return (gProtIntCards = arrFoods.map((item, i) => {
    return (item = arrFoods[i][macro]);
  }));
};
const addMacros = (nintCards, macroIntCards, arrFoods) => {
  let arrAdd = [];

  arrAdd = nintCards(arrFoods).map((item, i) => {
    return (item = nintCards(arrFoods)[i] * macroIntCards()[i]);
  });

  return arrAdd.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
};

function addFoodWeight(arrFoods,addOuputsFoods,inputCarb,inputProt, inputLip) {
  arrFoods.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.foodWeight = item.weight_int * addOuputsFoods(arrFoods, inputCarb,inputProt, inputLip)[i];
  });
}

function nintCards(arrFoods) {
  // return array

  return arrFoods.map((item) => {
    return item.n_int_card;
  });
  
}

export {macrosIndex, gMacrosIntCards, addMacros, addFoodWeight, nintCards};
```

component (**arrFoods is pass how to parameter in the second line function addOuputsFoods: const arrOuputsFoods = nintCards(arrFoods)**);

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../../UserContext.js";
import NumberFormat from "react-number-format";

import { macrosIndex, gMacrosIntCards, addMacros, addFoodWeight, nintCards, } from "../../functions/functionsParams";





const InputMacros = () => {
  const {
    inputProt,
    setInputProt,
    inputLip,
    setInputLip,
    inputCarb,
    setInputCarb,
    arrFoods,
  } = useContext(UserContext);

  function updateInputProt(event) {
    const inputProtein = event.target.value;
    setInputProt(inputProtein);
    addFoodWeight(arrFoods,addOuputsFoods,inputCarb,inputProt, inputLip);
  }
  function updateInputLip(event) {
    const inputLipids = event.target.value;
    setInputLip(inputLipids);
    addFoodWeight(arrFoods,addOuputsFoods,inputCarb,inputProt, inputLip);
  }
  function updateInputCarb(event) {
    const inputCarbohidrats = event.target.value;
    setInputCarb(inputCarbohidrats);
    addFoodWeight(arrFoods,addOuputsFoods,inputCarb,inputProt, inputLip);
  }

  /////////////////

 /*  function addFoodWeight() {
    arrFoods.forEach((item, i) => {
      item.foodWeight = item.weight_int * addOuputsFoods()[i];
    });
  }  */

  /* function nintCards() {
    // return array

    return arrFoods.map((item) => {
      return item.n_int_card;
    });

  } */

  function addOuputsFoods() {
    //insert the exchanges of starchyFoods
    const arrOuputsFoods = nintCards();

    arrOuputsFoods.forEach((i) => {
      arrOuputsFoods[starchyFoodsIndex()[i]] =
        nintStarchyFoods() / starchyFoodsIndex().length;
    });

    //insert the exchanges of proteinFoods
    arrOuputsFoods.forEach((i) => {
      arrOuputsFoods[proteinFoodIndex()[i]] =
        nintProtein() / proteinFoodIndex().length;
    });
    //insert the exchanges of fats
    arrOuputsFoods.forEach((i) => {
      arrOuputsFoods[lipidsIndex()[i]] = nintLipids() / lipidsIndex().length;
    });

    return arrOuputsFoods;
  }

  function starchyFoodsIndex() {
    return macrosIndex("starchyFoods", arrFoods);
  }

  function nintStarchyFoods() {
    return (inputCarb - totalHc()) / 14;
  }

  function totalHc() {
    return addMacros(nintCards, gHcIntCards);
  }

  function proteinFoodIndex() {
    return macrosIndex("proteinFoods", arrFoods);
  }

  function lipidsIndex() {
    return macrosIndex("fats", arrFoods);
  }

  function totalProtein() {
    starchyFoodsIndex();

    return addMacros(nintCards, gProtIntCards);
  }

  function totalLipids() {
    starchyFoodsIndex();

    proteinFoodIndex();

    return addMacros(nintCards, gLipIntCards);
  }

  function nintProtein() {
    return (inputProt - totalProtein()) / 7;
  }

  function nintLipids() {
    return (inputLip - totalLipids()) / 5;
  }

  function gProtIntCards() {
    return gMacrosIntCards("prot", arrFoods);
  }

  function gLipIntCards() {
    return gMacrosIntCards("lip", arrFoods);
  }

  function gHcIntCards() {
    return gMacrosIntCards("hc", arrFoods);
  }

  //////////////////////

  const formatProt = () => {
    let formatProt = Math.round(inputProt);
    /* formatProt=`${formatProt}g` */
    return formatProt;
  };

  const formatLip = () => {
    return Math.round(inputLip);
  };

  const formatCarb = () => {
    return Math.round(inputCarb);
  };

  return (
    <form className="col p-3 mt-4">
      <div className="form-row d-flex flex-row ">
        <div className="col-md-4 mb-3">
          <div className="divMacros">
            <label>
              {" "}
              <h4>g Prot</h4>
            </label>
            <NumberFormat
              name="inputProt"
              onChange={updateInputProt}
              type="number"
              className="inputMacros mt-1"
              placeholder="Pro g"
              /* suffix={'g'} */
              /* displayType={'text'} */
              value={formatProt()}
            ></NumberFormat>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-4 mb-3">
          <div className="divMacros">
            <label>
              {" "}
              <h4>g Fats </h4>
            </label>
            <input
              name="inputLip"
              onChange={updateInputLip}
              type="number"
              className="inputMacros mt-1"
              placeholder="Lip g"
              value={formatLip()}
            ></input>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-4 mb-3">
          <div className="divMacros">
            <label>
              {" "}
              <h4>g Carb </h4>
            </label>
            <input
              name="inputCarb"
              onChange={updateInputCarb}
              type="number"
              className="inputMacros mt-1"
              placeholder="CH g"
              value={formatCarb()}
            ></input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default InputMacros;
```

Comment: I don't see where you declare the `arrFoods` variable used in `addOputsFoods`. This code should throw a different error to the one you've shown, regarding the undeclared variable.

Comment: PS I don't see anything specific to React in your code - even if this is used in a React app, nothing about this code actually uses anything specific to React

Comment: arrFoods is pass how to parameter in the second line function addOuputsFoods: const arrOuputsFoods = nintCards(arrFoods);

Comment: right, that's what I'm referring to - what is `arrFoods` at that point? There's no such variable in the code you've shared

Comment: it is true forget to declare it,  arrFoods is an array of objects, I just edited it

Comment: thanks for the update - but while you might expect it to be an array of objects, it's obvious from the error message that it is in fact `undefined`. Try stepping through your code to debug this yourself (presumably something is wrong in the `UserContext`) - we can't help you with that since you don't share enough of the code.

Comment: Also where is addOutputsFoods called?

Comment: Thanks for your support, I'll keep trying

Comment: I have uploaded the complete code

Comment: `addOuputsFoods` function clearly pass for some refactors, cause in some cases it does receive a lot of parameters, in the function declaration it doesn't, there is some comments with `addOutputsFoods` calls without parameter either. Just take a look at that, however it looks like if you just pass `arrFoods` to `const arrOuputsFoods = nintCards(arrFoods);` it might work

Comment: Thanks Vinicius, I have passed the parameter (const arrOuputsFoods = nintCards(arrFoods) )but it still does not work.

Comment: Thanks for your support guys, I was able to solve it, I had to pass the parameter arrFoods also to the addMacros function & const arrOuputsFoods = nintCards(arrFoods);

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your support guys, I was able to solve it, I had to pass the parameter arrFoods also to the addMacros function & const arrOuputsFoods = nintCards(arrFoods);